# AlarmManager not triggering repeated alarm on proper time

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat, repeatingalarm

I am developing an application for Android `Lollipop` and `KitKat` devices. The application needs to call an API in every predefined interval (Based on the interval received from server). I am doing this using `AlarmManager` class.
But the problem is it works till some time then stops.

Say for example If I set to start the alarm at 08:00 AM with an interval of 30 minutes it works till 11:00AM (aprx) and then alarm doesn't trigger.

If I set a long interval (eg : 8 hours from current time, still same issue happens, not reiggering even once )

**Code**

```
public void setRepeatedAlarm(Context context, int requestCode, long next, long interval, Intent intent) {
   PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
   AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
   am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, next, interval, sender);
}
```

**Function calling**

```
AlarmHandleManager.get().setRepeatedAlarm(this, Constants.SchedulerRequestCodes.UPLOAD_LOG, date.getTime(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, intent);
```

Let me know if any one can figure out the issue.
Have seen a bug reported in lollipop in Google bug tracker, If that is the case let me know if there is any alternative solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think it's a bug since it's already mentioned in the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

> **Note**: As of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact. Because this method has been available since API 3, your application can safely call it and be assured that it will get similar behavior on both current and older versions of Android.
>
> **Note**: as of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact. If your application needs precise delivery times then it must use one-time exact alarms, rescheduling each time as described above. Legacy applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to have all of their alarms, including repeating alarms, treated as exact.
>
> **Note**: Beginning with API 19 (Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, android.app.PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long, android.app.PendingIntent). Applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when requested.

Comment: As per the documentation it says from API 19 "alarm delivery is inexact". but in my case it is not even triggering.

Comment: yeah but the it says the repeat